# Why does my Apache Camel conditional route always execute the first option?

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I have a Camel route that (among other things) is supposed to run a validator, but only if a certain property is set, namely `com.acme.ValidatorOn`.

The relevant portion of the route looks like this:

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>{{com.acme.ValidatorOn}} == true</simple>
        <to uri="validator:MyWebService.xsd" />
    </when>
</choice>
```

When I noticed that the validator was ALWAYS getting executed even when the property was set to `false`, I started experimented with the condition.

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>{{com.blahblahthiswillnotwork.ValidatorOn}} == true</simple>
        <to uri="validator:MyWebService.xsd" />
    </when>
</choice>
```

Even with a bogus property name, the validator was still executing. So I took it further, and also added an `<otherwise>`:

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>5 == 6</simple>
        <log message="first choice" />
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <log message="second choice"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

This prints "first choice". No matter what expression I put in the `<simple>`, the first choice is executed. I've tried expressions that obviously are not true such as `'foo' == 'bar'` and even just gibberish.

I've looked over the Camel documentation on content based routing and there doesn't seem to be an error in the way I'm setting this up. I'm using Camel 2.8.1 and Java 8 update 45.

Below is the full route, just in case there could be something else in the route that is messing this up (names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
<route autoStartup="false" id="com.acme.doStuffRoute">
    <from uri="spring-ws:rootqname:{namepace}doStuff?endpointMapping=#com.acme.EndpointMapping"/>
    <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_QUERY">
        <simple>certainProperty=${ref:certainProperty}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
        <constant>POST</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <policy ref="com.acme.Administrators">
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>{{com.acme.ValidatorOn}} == true</simple>
                <to uri="validator:MyWebService.xsd"/>
            </when>
        </choice>
        <to pattern="InOut" uri="xslt:/xslt/do-stuff-request.xsl?transformerFactory=transformerFactory&amp;uriResolver=uriResolver"/>
        <to ref="com.acme.ToLogging"/>
        <transform>
            <method bean="msgTransform" method="encrypt"/>
        </transform>
        <to uri="ref:doMoreStuffEndpoint"/>
        <transform>
            <method bean="msgTransform" method="decrypt"/>
        </transform>
        <to ref="com.acme.FromLogging"/>
        <to uri="xslt:/xslt/do-stuff-request.xsl?transformerFactory=transformerFactory&amp;uriResolver=uriResolver"/>
        <process ref="com.acme.MetricsProcessor"/>
    </policy>
</route>
```

Comment: Where did you find any example of using "{{ }}" placeholder instead of "${ }" ?

Comment: I have a bean called `springPropertyConfigurer` that defines a placeholder prefix of `{{` and a placeholder suffix of `}}` for any properties that come from a specific properties file. This works in other routes in my application.

Comment: As for me the problem looks strange, but generally speaking SIMPLE is not recommended to be used if the left side is not function evaluated with data from exchange ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7428?jql=project%20%3D%20CAMEL%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Resolved%20AND%20text%20~%20%22simple%22 )

Comment: Look at the comments in the link i posted.
Have you tried to replace it with spel?
<spel>#{com.blahblahthiswillnotwork.ValidatorOn == true}</spel>

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: No. We have tried <spel> and <xpath> but generally get the same syntax or unrecognized argument errors for the left side of the expression. We're considering that we may have to handle this in a Java bean.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but might be helpful in a future. From [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html):

The parser is limited to only support a single operator.
To enable it the left value must be enclosed in `${ }`. The syntax is:

```
${leftValue} OP rightValue
```

You must use camel-simple expression. I.e. set header with the value of your property, then use `${headers.yourHeader}` inside `<when>`.

**EDIT:** I found a better solution: use a camel-simple way to get property: `${properties:com.acme.ValidatorOn}`